# my swift method gives no output

Tags: swift, class, methods

I don't really know what is wrong with this that i cant get any output

```
class Shape {
    var numberOfSides : Int = 3
    var name : String
    init(name : String){
        self.name = name
    }
    func print() -> String {
        return("numberOfSides  :   \(numberOfSides)")
    }
}
var Square = Shape("moraba")

println(Square.print())
```

Comment: Works for me. // If you're using a Playground, don't forget to display the "Assistant editor" (Xcode 6) or the "Debug area" (Xcode 7) to see the `println` output.

Comment: Be mindful of conventions. It's unusual to have a variable whose name starts with an uppercase letter (like `Square`), and the preferred way to have a string representation of an object is to have a `description : String` computed property (instead of a `print` method). Following conventions helps other people (like us) not trip reading your code.

Comment: Also be aware that in Swift 2.0 `println` has been changed to `print`, meaning that when you migrate (eventually), having your own methods named `print` may be confusing and/or conflict with the system functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike normal methods and functions `init()` methods require to pass the first parameter name

```
let square = Shape(name:"moraba")
println(square.print())
```